# Autoboxing in Hash Map returns NULL

Tags: java, hashmap

I wrote the following code and Output i expect is  'Hello World'

I got null , Can some one explains the behaviour.

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class Test {
  static HashMap<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte b = 1;
    hm.put(1, "Hello World");
    String s = hm.get(b);
    System.out.println("The result is: " + s);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot perform auto boxing of byte to Integer.

This confusion cames from fact that Map's get method takes key as Object, not as Integer as specified in type of the key of your map. So you can do something like:

```
String s = hm.get("hello");
```

which has no sence, of course, but there will be no compilation errors.

To fix you should convert byte to Integer (or int) manually:

```
String s = hm.get((int)b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is autoboxing `b` to a `Byte`, which is not an `Integer`.

Even if it could infer the Integer type, Java won't perform an automatic widening cast *and* an autobox conversion (ever).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with autoboxing. HashMap works internally with Object Classes. Look into the source code of HashMap.java

```
public V get(Object key) {
    [...]
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
            e != null;
            e = e.next) {

        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Entries are stored in the table by their `hashCode()` method. So far your `get(b)` line with a byte as Key would work, since this is true:

```
byte b = 1;
int i = 1;
((Object)b).hashCode() == ((Object)i).hashCode() //true, both are 1
```

So the for loop in the `HashMap.get` Method finds an corresponding Entry in the table.
But then there is this `if` statement. Lets break it down:

1. `(e.hash == hash)` This is still true. The `put` Method  also uses the default `hashCode()` Method when creating new Entries and stores this value.
2. `(k = e.key) == key` This is not true. `(Object)b != (Object)i`. This must be the exact same object to be true.
3. `key.equals(k)` This is also not true:

So your entry is found but the byte key fails the futher checks and you get null as result. Unless you use integer.